# How to put a div at the bottom of the page, but move it if the page overflows

Tags: html, css, position

I am making an html page which by default will have some divs at the top, some blank space and then another div at the bottom of the page. I can use position fixed or absolute to make the div stay at the bottom. The 'studentcontainer' divs should start of thin meaning that they do not take up all the space on the page. I would like for the 'buttoncontainer' div to stay at the bottom of the page, with some blank space above it, UNLESS the 'studentcontainers' are expanded in which case I would like for the 'buttoncontainer' to get pushed down the page with no blank space above it (except for a small margin I have set)

```js
< script >
  $('#expand1').on("click", function(e) {
    $('#details1').fadeToggle(250);
    if (e.target.textContent === "Expand") {
      e.target.textContent = "Collapse";
    } else {
      e.target.textContent = "Expand";
    }
  }); <
</script> 
<script >
  $('#expand2').on("click", function(e) {
    $('#details2').fadeToggle(250);
    if (e.target.textContent === "Expand") {
      e.target.textContent = "Collapse";
    } else {
      e.target.textContent = "Expand";
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

```css
.elementborder {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 428px;
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #2c4e8d;
}

.studentcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#studentheading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #2c4e8d;
    border-style: none none solid ;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

.detailscontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    display: none;
}

.valueselection {
    width: 42%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.locationselection {
    width: 42%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}

input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.commentbox {
    height: 30px;
    width: 86.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.expandcontainer {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.expandbutton {
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}

.removecontainer {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.removebutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="elementborder" style="border-color: white;">
  <div class="studentcontainer" id="studentcontainer1">
    <div id="studentheading">
      <div class="name" style="padding-left: 4%;">
        <t>Squidward Tentacles</t>
      </div>
      <div class="ako">
        <t>13GWZ</t>
      </div>
      <div class="expandcontainer">
        <button id="expand1" class="expandbutton"><t style = "text-decoration: underline">Expand</t></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailscontainer" id="details1">
      <SELECT name="valueselection" class="valueselection">
        <option>-Select the value that has been shown-</option>
        <option value='pride'>Pride</option>
        <option value='quality'>Quality</option>
        <option value='respect'>Respect</option>
      </SELECT>
      <SELECT name="locationselection" class="locationselection">
        <option>-Select the location-</option>
        <option value='a-block'>A-Block</option>
        <option value='s-block'>S-Block</option>
        <option value='t-block'>T-Block</option>
      </SELECT>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="5" name="number" />
      <input class="commentbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter any aditional comments (optional)" />
      <div class="removecontainer">
        <button id="remove1" class="removebutton"><t style = "text-decoration: underline;">Remove</t></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="studentcontainer" id="studentcontainer1">
    <div id="studentheading">
      <div class="name" style="padding-left: 4%;">
        <t>Patrick Star</t>
      </div>
      <div class="ako">
        <t>13GWZ</t>
      </div>
      <div class="expandcontainer">
        <button id="expand2" class="expandbutton"><t style = "text-decoration: underline">Expand</t></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailscontainer" id="details2">
      <SELECT name="valueselection" class="valueselection">
        <option>-Select the value that has been shown-</option>
        <option value='pride'>Pride</option>
        <option value='quality'>Quality</option>
        <option value='respect'>Respect</option>
      </SELECT>
      <SELECT name="locationselection" class="locationselection">
        <option>-Select the location-</option>
        <option value='a-block'>A-Block</option>
        <option value='s-block'>S-Block</option>
        <option value='t-block'>T-Block</option>
      </SELECT>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="5" name="number" />
      <input class="commentbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter any aditional comments (optional)" />
      <div class="removecontainer">
        <button id="remove2" class="removebutton"><t style = "text-decoration: underline;">Remove</t></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <button class="cancelbutton"><bt>Cancel</bt></button>
    <button class="continuebutton"><wt>Continue</wt></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Without any positioning the bottom div, with the buttons, floats right underneath the other divs, which I do not want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qI1p.png)

[With position: absolute the div starts off in the right place (ignore the weird sizing)...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GNW.png)

[But then when the above divs are expanded, the buttoncontainer stays where it is and overlaps the other divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nEVu.png)

I have now added some of the code, but it does not seem to be working correctly when I run it, so sorry if it is not very helpful.

Comment: Kindly add the code

Comment: @MihirK98 I have added the code now, but when it is run it does not seem to work right. Hopefully it will be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay firstly, don't use

```
position: fixed;
```

Use

```
position: absolute;
```

Now don't use top and left.
Use bottom and left instead

```
bottom: 10px;
left: 0;
```

I think this should work
(When the page expands the div will still stick to the bottom)

If this is not what you want, then get the height of other divs and set the your div's position accordingly

Comment: This has not worked because the div stays floating at the bottom of the screen and does not move down when the page overflows

Answer (score 0):

If you can share your code I can help you better but as far as I understand from your explanation you want 'Cancel' and 'Continue' buttons to always stay at bottom. So I have created a sample for you. Check the snipped below if this what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

    /* Check these codes */
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    header,
    footer {
      flex: none;
      background-color: yellow;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    main {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      flex: auto;
    }

    /* These are not related to your topic it's just for styling */
    .some-divs {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .btn-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .btn {
      height: 40px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      color: white;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    This is header
  </header>
  <main>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
    <p class="some-divs">Your div</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="btn" type="button" name="button">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn" type="button" name="button">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is not quite what I was trying to do. I was looking for a way to have the buttons at the bottom of the page by default, even if there is no divs above to keep them there. Then I wanted the buttons to be pushed down if the page overflows. I have found a solution and added it to my post.

Comment: Okay now I understand your purpose.  It's good that if you solve the problem.